Blazor - for loop index value as onclick parameter not working as expected, creating new variable in each iteration is required. Why?
I am creating a simple tetris game using Blazor WASM. The purpose of the following code is to render a grid of pixels as a game board and send a ROW and COL values as parameters to a function in a onclick event to log which "pixel" has been clicked.
Can someone explain me why this code does not work: (it sends the same (last) value of row and col when clicking on any "pixel")
<div class="board">

    @for (int row = 0; row < _height; row++)
    {
        for (int col = 0; col < _width; col++)
        {
            <div class="pixel" data-row="@row" data-col="@col" @onclick="@(() =>  
                     LogClickedPixel($"Clicked pixel {row} - {col}"))"></div>
        }
    }

</div>

While this code works? (sends the row and col of the clicked "pixel")
<div class="board">

    @for (int row = 0; row < _height; row++)
    {
        for (int col = 0; col < _width; col++)
        {
            //assignement to a new variable is required
            int _row = row;
            int _col = col;

            <div class="pixel" data-row="@row" data-col="@col" @onclick="@(() => 
                 LogClickedPixel($"Clicked pixel {_row} - {_col}"))"></div>
        }
    }

</div>

I want to understand why Blazor needs the variables to be reassigned to new ones. Arent they also temporary living in a scope of the single for loop iteration?
I want to understand why the reassignment is required for Blazor

This is a known effect, but I'm curious-- if you add a key to your pixel div, does it still do this?

https://stackoverflow.com/a/271447/2658697

It's called the Captured Variables, This behavior is triggered because you use a lambda expression
() => LogClickedPixel($"Clicked pixel {_row} - {_col}"))

where the outer scoped variable (row,col) not actually defined in the lambda's inner scope.
In fact, the solution you provided is the right solution because in this scenario you need a
Scoped Variables :
 int _row = row;
 int _col = col;

more details:
captured variable in a loop in c sharp
How to capture a variable in C#
Access to modified captured variable
csharp code blocks
